# Why Django raising ValueError?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

This is my view.py file under my project folder.
When I add a value in ToDo list it raises this error?

> The view my_day.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import List
from .form import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = List.objects.all
            messages.success(request, ('Task Added'))
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'all_items': all_items})

     else:

        all_items = List.objects.all
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'all_items': all_items})
```

Comment: What if you made a POST request, but the `form` was *not* valid? Then the codepath does *not* call a `return render(..)`, it will return `None`, and thus breaks the "contract".

Comment: Furthermore the above is typically not a good idea, since it returns content for a POST request, typically you want to implement the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: It returns "The view my_day.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."
same error

Comment: @TAHMIDHASAHNAFIS: exactly, do you understand *why*?

Comment: when user hit submit, it sends a post request; here I told to render index file, I cant understand why it returns None instead of my index page with list.

Comment: Because `if form.is_valid():` is false, and there is no `else` clause for *that condition*, and no codepath *after* the inner and outer `if`.

Comment: Why each word is not valid! and how can I access my index page with my list? @williem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you have 3 possible outcomes based on the `if` conditions but only 2 of them returns a `HttpResonse` object. More specifically, the `if form.is_valid()` only returns a `HttpResponse` object if this condition passes. If it doesn't, it will return `None` (basically nothing) because there is no `else` condition or other fallback.

You need to add an else condition to the `if form.is_valid()`. More so, you should implement another approach than to serve content on a `POST` request. As [WillemVanOnsem have commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52990428/why-django-raising-valueerror/52990495?noredirect=1#comment92886161_52990428), check out the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. I have replaced the `return render(...)` instances where needed to achieve this, but will need some tweaking to work, for instance replace the view name (should be defined in your `urls.py` file).

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = List.objects.all
            messages.success(request, ('Task Added'))
            # Replaced the render(...) with a redirect instead.
            # Replace "index" with the name of the view (if not index)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            # Added fallback if the form.is_valid() didn't pass
            messages.failure(request, ('Failed when saving task'))
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'all_items': all_items})

    else:
        all_items = List.objects.all
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'all_items': all_items})
```

Comment: I think it might be better to return a redirect in case the form is successful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I'm new in Django, So can't implement using redirect :(   @William

Comment: @TAHMIDHASANNAFIS Did you replace the `TODO` section with a `return render(...)` instance? Because my example code was not complete, just a way to show what needs to be done and why you get he error. But just as Willem says, you should try another approach than to return content on a `POST` request.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True, I have updated my answer to achieve this pattern instead. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Johan: normally one only redirects in case the form was successful, since if it is not successful, it makes more sense to display the errors, and resubmitting an invalid form should - usually - not have side-effects.

Comment: @TareqMonwer Did it solve your problem or are you still having issues?